# How I can start IE in 32bit mode in webdriver.io

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am running an [WebDriver.io](http://webdriver.io/) test using [gulp-wdio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wdio) npm pakage 
on [selenium-standalone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone)

The Code that I run in gulp is:

```
gulp.task('e2e', function () {
return gulp.src('wdio.conf.js')
    .pipe(wdio({
        wdio: {
            specs: './test/features/**/*.feature'
        }
    }));
});
```

And my wdio.conf.js define browsers this way:

```
capabilities: [     
        {
            browserName: 'internet explorer',
            version: 'ANY'
        }
    ],
```

[How ever the typing is very slow](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5116), i had found on the internet that running 32 bit version of the web-driver resolves the issue, how ever I can't find how to configure the capabilities or some other place to run the IE32 bit driver by default... 
Any help will be appreciated @:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 2 days of research I had found the solution !!!

There is a configuration file that need to be supplied to the selenium standalone 
as shown in this [Example](https://github.com/vvo/selenium-standalone#example)
so our final setup is done in this way:

We have a configuration file called wdio.browsers.setup.js that contains the browsers setup:

```
module.exports = {
    baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com',
    version: '3.3.1',
    drivers: {
        chrome: {
            version: '2.29',
            arch: process.arch,
            // - Recent versions of the driver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
            baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
        },
        ie: {
            version: '3.0.0',
            arch: 'ia32',
            // - Recent versions of the driver: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
            baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com'
        },
        firefox: {
            version: '0.15.0',
            arch: process.arch,
            baseURL: 'https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download'
        }
    }
};
```

and then inside wdio.conf.js we load it and assign to a special parameters

```
let browsersSetup = require('./wdio.browsers.setup');
exports.config = {

   seleniumArgs: browsersSetup,
    seleniumInstallArgs: browsersSetup,
```

**After that all is working fine @:-)**

Note: if you have your web-driver installed globally remove the global setup first it's located in:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Then you can run the local installation using:

```
./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install --config=../../wdio.browsers.setup.js
```

Comment: Vote up then :-)

Comment: Good stuff @OBender!  I was stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below working solution for IE browser to install 32 bit:

```
services: ["selenium-standalone"],
seleniumArgs: {
    drivers: {`enter code here`
        ie: {
            version: "3.4.0", // or whatever latest is
            arch: "ia32", // forces use of 32 bit driver
            baseURL: "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com"
        },
    },
},
seleniumInstallArgs: {
    drivers: {
        ie: {
            version: "3.4.0", // or whatever latest is
            arch: "ia32", // forces use of 32 bit driver
            baseURL: "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com"
        },
    },
},
```